# Python's sh module - Running Command wrapper in background

Tags: python, background-process, python-sh

When using python's [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) module (not a part of stdlib), I can call a program in my path as a function and run it in the background:

```
from sh import sleep

# doesn't block
p = sleep(3, _bg=True)
print("prints immediately!")
p.wait()
print("...and 3 seconds later")
```

And I can use sh's `Command` wrapper and pass in the absolute path of an executable (helpful if the executable isn't in my path or has characters such as `.`):

```
import sh
run = sh.Command("/home/amoffat/run.sh")
run()
```

But trying to run the wrapped executable in the background, as follows:

```
import sh
run = sh.Command("/home/amoffat/run.sh", _bg=True)
run()
```

Fails with a traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_bg'
```

How can I run an executable wrapped by `sh.Command` in the background? Looking for an elegant solution.

EDIT:

I used the python interpreter for testing passing `_bg` to the command (not the wrapper), which I now realize is a bad way to test for blocking and non-blocking processes:

```
>>> import sh
>>> hello = sh.Command("./hello.py")
>>> hello(_bg=True) # 5 second delay before the following prints and prompt is returned
HI
HI
HI
HI
HI
```

With hello.py being as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time

for i in xrange(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    print "HI"
```

Comment: You could use popen / subprocess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import sh
run = sh.Command("/home/amoffat/run.sh", _bg=True) # this isn't your command, 
                                                   # so _bg does not apply
run()
```

Instead, do

```
import sh
run = sh.Command("/home/amoffat/run.sh")
run(_bg=True)
```

(BTW, the `subprocess` module provides a much less magical way to do such things.)

Comment: It looks like `_bg` doesn't apply to the command either. This is what I originally attempted before trying to pass `_bg` into the `sh.Command` wrapper. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @billyw, Post a complete, runnable file and your full traceback for the case where you do this.

Comment: Your solution wasn't causing a traceback, it was that the process was still blocking. It turns out I needed to assign the running command to a variable, i.e. `p = run(_bg=True)`. Running `run(_bg=True)` alone caused the process to block. You solved the problem that I originally posted, though, so I will accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: "It turns out I needed to assign the running command to a variable" <-- You're still misunderstanding what's going on. You should post your complete, real, preferably runnable code and something the corresponding output that shows what's happening.

Comment: You'll need to give `run(...)` a name if you want to call a method on it later, of course, but it doesn't alter the behavior you're mentioning.

Comment: I edited my post with more information. I was testing `sh` in the python interpreter, not by running it in a file (whoops). Thanks for following up on my misunderstandings.

Comment: Can I keep on running this background process in the background even after the python script exits?